# java JSON optstring with wildcard

Tags: java, json, parsing, wildcard

response 1:

```
{
    "myJsonKey":"myJsonValue1",
    "abcResultKey":"resultValue1",
    "otherKey":"otherValue1"
}
```

other response:

```
{
    "myJsonKey":"myJsonValue2",
    "xyztResultKey":"resultValue2",
    "otherKey":"otherValue2"
}
```

I have a JSONObject that ends with a ResultKey and whose starting string is unknown. I want to get the value of the key ending with "ResultKey". The string to the left of ResultKey(abc, xyzt) is unknown. But always at least 1 character or more long. Also, getting the name of this key (abcResultKey or xyztResultKey etc.)

Is there a way to use wildcards? like *ResultKey, ends with "ResultKey"

I have tried:
String valueOfResultKey = jsonObject.optString("*ResultKey");

But it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Parse the json to a map?

Comment: No. I just want to get key name that ends with "ResulsKey" and it's value

Comment: If you parse the json to a Map object, the keys of the map will be the same as the keys of the original json.

Comment: if I can get the unknown resultKey and its value, any solution will OK for me.

Comment: If jsonObject is [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject) you can simply iterate on `jsonObject.keys()` .

Comment: @assylias Yes jsonObject is [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject). if i can't find a solution with wildcard or more effective solution, I will use iterator. but I don't want to use iterator. because  there are many key exist.